# jQuery find and replace anchor in child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some HTML that follows this pattern:

```
<p class="title" data-section-title="" style="left: 0px;">
    <a href="#">Overview</a>
</p>
```

I need to change the hash to an anchor, something like `<a href="#tab1">Overview</a>`

I can't seem to be able to select this using jQuery, mainly because I'm terrible with it. I was trying something like `$("p.title > a").attr("href","http://www.someURL.com");`  just trying to change the href.

Any help greatly appreciated! thanks

Comment: I don't see any wrong in your code

Comment: you need to put that function inside an event, such as http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is perfectly alright. I smell something fishy though.

I think you are trying to access elements even before the are there or jquery isn't loaded. Otherwise that simple code should've worked.

Try this:

- Check if jquery is loaded
- Wrap your code in DOM ready:

Wrapping is like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //code goes here
});
```

Comment: You're right, stupid mistake that I didn't even realize. you can't select an element that isn't loaded. Thank you!

Comment: @MannfromReno, glad to have helped you ;)

Answer (score 2):

As you can see, this works in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GY5D7/ .
Perhaps there is something wrong with when you initialize the script. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p.title > a").attr("href","http://www.someURL.com");
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much, the elements were not loaded yet so obviously nothing could be selected or modified.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code it should work

```
$('p.title').find('a').attr('href',"http://www.someURL.com");
```

Sorry I am wrong :(

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Try this fiddle. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7nvgL/2/)
Your code seems to be alright though.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $("p.title > a").attr("href","#tab1");
        alert($("p.title > a").attr("href"));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When that Javascript is firing, is your HTML rendered? It may not be.

#### Easiest fix: Wrap in [`$(document).ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

There are two ways. Longhand:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("p.title > a").attr("href","http://www.someURL.com");
});
```

Shorthand:

```
$(function() {
    $("p.title > a").attr("href","http://www.someURL.com");
});
```

#### Other ways

You don't *have* to wrap it in `$(document).ready()`. If you place that script at the end of the body, then it can work:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="title" data-section-title="" style="left: 0px;">
        <a href="#">Overview</a>
    </p>
    <script>
        $("p.title > a").attr("href","http://www.someURL.com");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### You might not have jQuery loaded

Check your console by hitting <kbd>F12</kbd>. If you see an error that looks like this:

**Chrome:**

[image: jQuery not loaded in Chrome]

**Firefox:**

[image: jQuery not loaded in Firefox]

**Internet Explorer:**

[image: jQuery not loaded in Internet Explorer]

Then you need to include jQuery in your document

Comment: Thanks, you're also right, I appreciate the answer/help.